# FolderBrowserDialog won't show in a single .cs file without Form

Tags: c#, csc, folderbrowserdialog

I am trying to code a program which is executed when a file is right clicked in windows, and then a context menu feature named 'Move to' executes a file in the windows registry HKEY ClASSES. It ought to parse in "%1" as argument when it executes, so that my program knows where the file is located. However, when I compile my single .cs file, the FolderBrowserDialog won't show. I am suspecting that it is because I haven't initialized some kind of form before I call it. Is it possible in some way to choose a folder from a single c# file without including Forms?

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Windows.Forms;


public class MoveTo : Form 
{

    public static string current_file_path;
    public static string new_file_path;
    public static string file_name;

    public static void Main(string[] args){
        if (args.Length > 0)
        {
            current_file_path = (string) args[0];
            file_name = (string) current_file_path.Replace(Path.GetDirectoryName(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[1]), "");
            var browser = new FolderBrowserDialog();

            if (browser.ShowDialog()==DialogResult.OK)
            {
                new_file_path = browser.SelectedPath + file_name;
            }else
            {
                Environment.Exit(1);
            }
            try
            {
                File.Move(current_file_path, new_file_path);    
            }catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you bypass the argument check and try to show the FBD in a debugger, with this exact code, you will see *System.Threading.ThreadStateException: 'Current thread must be set to single thread apartment (STA) mode before OLE calls can be made. Ensure that your Main function has STAThreadAttribute marked on it. This exception is only raised if a debugger is attached to the process.'*

As per the error message, this exception won't be raised if no debugger is attached. Put an `[STAThread]` attribute on your `Main` method, like you normally see in any windows forms app:

```
[STAThread]
public static void Main(string[] args)
{ 
  ...
```

I also recommend you add an `else` for your outer if, to show an error if no arguments are passed (otherwise your app will exit silently

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked! Do you know how I can hide the console, so that when the program runs it only shows the browserdialog but not the cmd prompt?

Comment: Did you make it as a console app ?

Comment: I merely created a .cs file with vim and then ran it.

Comment: So you wrote a .cs file, compiled it with csc.exe? Did you specify /target:winexe when compiling? https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/net-framework-essentials/0596001657/apds06.html

Comment: No. I only wrote csc myFile.cs

Comment: Odd mix of utilities; vim is a bit archaic - why not try Visual Studio Code, or the free version of Visual Studio? Anyhows, give that argument a try so it makes a windows forms app not a console one (console apps show a dos window when run)

Comment: It worked. The reason is that I do not want to create a form, I have tried that, but I think it's more messy. I just wanted to make a single file, easy to make and compile, that would give the exact same output. Again, thanks for you help.